# ASP.NET MVC2 Post to SSL and WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture, ssl, https

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 application hosted in a non-secure environment (http), also I have my account services (WCF) on an SSL server.
I need to post a form that is on the non-secure http application to a secure SSL and access then the service. By no means I'm allowed to host the application in the SSL server (because it will loose the load balancing).

What could be the best approach to solve this problem?
1. Do the normal post in the mvc application and call the SSL hosted WCF Service.
2. Create an mvc application in the SSL server, then make the non-secure application call an action on the secure one, then the secure mvc call the service.
3. Any other approach?

I'm kinda new and will help me lots. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an observation but the data is either sensitive or not - If it's sensitive then it should be SSL all the way across the public internet - without exception. Data security is very important and if it's a load balancing issue, you need to consider either a different architecture or more servers. If the data is not sensitive (and I'd ask why the WCF service is SSL) then just relay the data

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Do the normal post in the mvc application and call the SSL hosted
>   WCF Service.

NO. I think you actually need to use SSL because the data you're sending is quite sensitive. so make a normal POST is not an option.

> 2.Create an mvc application in the SSL server, then make the non-secure
>   application call an action on the
>   secure one

Could be. Very straightforward, but will add a new the load of a new app to maintain. however it's an acceptable cost.

#### Another solutions

- well, if this is an exceptional case, and there are no other cases when you have these security requirements, there are libraries as [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) that let you encrypt data without SSL. simpler and effective, in an exceptional case. you can use some kind of ModelBinder to hude this process. citing them:

  - *"Normally if you submit a form and you
    don’t use SSL, your data will be sent
    in plain text. But SSL is neither
    supported by every webhost nor it’s
    easy to install/apply sometimes. So I
    created this plug-in in order that
    you are able to encrypt your data
    fast and simple. jCryption uses the
    public-key algorithm of RSA for the encryption."* (via [JCryption main page](http://www.jcryption.org/))
- if are going to need SSL often, I would look for some kind of SSL gateway to  accept SSL requests in the SSL server and redirect them **internally** -attention, just internally. I mean inside your local network. do not let that data to travel plain among the internet! point- to the plain HTTP server and sent the response back to the client via SSL again. Anyway, I think it's less scalable and manageable than make it in the normal fashion looking for a way to adapt your load balancing to your new SSL requirements.